# How to Enable New Emojis keyboard in iOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uikeyboard, emoji

iOS 5.0 and above come with a standard Emoji keyboard. But there are some apps on app store that enable a new and different set of Emojis in iOS 5.1.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHGu0JgZ9X4

Does any one have an idea how to do that?

I have searched a lot, might be some key can be added in the PList, like it could be added in pre iOS 5.0, but I could not find one.

Comment: Hey, you got any answer for this means please share it. am also looking for this.